# undefined property :stdclass

Tags: drupal, error-handling

Im having this error continuously and i am not able to solve it.
what this error meaning ?? should i remove the badge module or to edit some modules.

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$badges_all in user_badges_block_view() (line 1347 of /home/dev_yasglobal/drupal.pk/drupal/sites/all/modules/user_badges/user_badges.module).
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in user_badges_block_view() (line 1350 of /home/dev_yasglobal/drupal.pk/drupal/sites/all/modules/user_badges/user_badges.module).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often times notices are shown because of a non-critical issue when the code in question was developed. It is best to search the issue cue in case this problem already exists (like in your case [http://drupal.org/node/931604]) and followup with the maintainer(s). This may be related to the module incompatibility between D6 and PHP 5.3.x or similar.